# For what values of $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ does the series $ \sum_{p=1}^{\infty}(\|v\|_{p}-\|v\|_{\infty})$ converge?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I saw this question here a few days ago and followed it, but it got erased so I'll ask separately
for what values of v does the series $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\left(\|v\|_{p}-\|v\|_{\infty}\right)$ converge.

If $n=1$ the answer is obvious.
I think I managed to show that if $n>1$ and be $v!=0$ and is constant in all coordinates then it won't converge.
If v only has one coordinate that isn't zero, it is also pretty obvious that it will converge.
Does anyone know how to solve it generally?

Comment: Well it seems the question (and my answer) have been deleted for some reason. So rather than type everything out and risk deletion again, I'll give you a hint. WLOG we can assume $1=v_1 \geq v_2\geq\ldots \geq v_n\geq 0$ (why?). Let $M$ be the number of components equal to $1$. Can you show if $M>1$ (that is, $\langle 1,1,\ldots,x_n\rangle$) the series diverges? Then can you show that if $M=1$, the series converges?

Comment: I don't really see the connection to the number of ones, can you explain? also, I think the previous question got erased because the person who asked erased it, so I don't think it will be erased if you answer here

Comment: Please do not re-ask questions that have been deleted.

Comment: hey, why? the answer isn't on the website anymore, and I wanted to know how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim is clear if $n=1$ or $v=\vec{0}$. So assume $n\geq 2$, $v\neq \vec{0}$, and $||v||_{\infty}=1$. In fact, by reordering and dividing by $||v||_{\infty}$, we can assume $1=|v_1|\geq |v_2|\geq \ldots \geq |v_n|$; we can also assume each $v_i$ is non-negative.

Recall the Limit Comparison Test: if $\sum_k a_k$, $\sum_k b_k$ are series of positive terms and $\lim_k a_k/b_k$ is a positive number, then the series converge or diverge together. Further, if the above limit is $0$ and $\sum_k b_k$ converges, $\sum_k a_k$ does as well. Also recall the $p$-series (no connection with the norm $p$ in this problem) $\sum_k k^{-p}$ converges for $p>1$ and diverges for $p\leq 1$.

By assumption we have $v_1=1$. Let $M$ be the total number of components equal to $1$; that is, $1=v_1=v_2=\ldots=v_M> v_{M+1}\geq \ldots \geq v_n$ (remember, this is post normalization). So
$$
||v||_p = \left( \sum _{i=1}^{n} v_i^p \right)^{1/p} = \left( M+\sum _{i=M+1}^{n} v_i^p \right)^{1/p}\geq   M^{1/p}
$$
$$
M^{1/p}\leq ||v||_p \leq \left(M+(n-M)v_{M+1}^p\right)^{1/p}
$$
Then by Squeeze Theorem we have
$$
\lim_{p\to\infty} p \left(||v||_p-1\right)= \log(M);
$$it's useful to work this out yourself. In other words: if more than one component has norm $1$, the corresponding series looks like the harmonic series, which diverges. So we must have $M=1$, i.e. $1=v_1>v_2\geq \ldots \geq v_n$. The good news is that this is also sufficient. It suffices to consider the vector $\langle 1,v_2,v_2,\ldots,v_2\rangle$; then we have
$$
\lim_{p\to\infty} p^{3/2} \left( \left(1+(n-1) v_{2}^p \right)^{1/p} -1\right)= 0
$$In this case, the series can be favorably compared to the convergent series $\sum_{k} k^{-3/2}$. So, in summary, the series $\displaystyle{
\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\left( ||{v}||_p-||{v}||_{\infty}\right)}$ converges if and only if there is exactly one index $j$ with $|v_j|=||{v}||_{\infty}$ and $|v_i|<|v_j|$ for $i\neq j$.

Comment: to show that the series diverges if M is greater than 1, I would choose the smallest v_i in order to bound the series from below and not above right?

Comment: My bad; fixing it now.

Comment: thank you. last thing, I think you should replace $\|v\|_{p}$ in $\lim _{p \rightarrow \infty} p\left(\|v\|_{p}-1\right)=\log (M)$ with the pth root of M